# Centrifuge Artificial Gravity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, centripetal-force, inertia

I just saw the following video: [NASA centrifuge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2EHwT33YCAw). In video, a person is walking on a huge spinning centrifuge.

But his weight is still acting downwards and there is no supporting force which will keep him from falling vertically to the ground. So why doesn't the person fall down?

Comment: The analogy of the string and the ball doesn't seem completely relevant: the ball actually moves downwards to a state of equilibrium with the gravitational force balancing the vertical component of the tension.

Comment: I think he is tethered ( supported with wire) in the gravity direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look carefully, you'll notice wires attached to the person, as well as a boom above him that follows him as he walks. The wires are more apparent in the closeup (starting at 0:24), especially if you look at the shadow. This apparatus is what supports him against the force of gravity.

[image]